# Async Console Application not closing

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, aws-sdk

I have the following code that uploads files to an AWS S3 bucket using the async method:

```
private static async Task Test()
 {
    
     var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.AFSouth1);

     await S3BucketHelper.ListBucketContentsAsync(s3Client, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["S3BucketName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["S3FolderName"]);

 }

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {

     try
     {
         Test().Wait();
         Console.WriteLine();
         //Environment.Exit(0);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e);
         throw;
     }

     finally
     {
         Environment.Exit(0);
     }
 }
```

When the application is done running, the ConsoleApplication does not seem to close, I keep getting the `Press any key to continue . . .` message.

This only happens when I am not running in debug mode.

I also explicitly closed the application using `Environment.Exit(0);` however this does not work.

Comment: Just because the console window stays open doesn't mean your app is still running.

Comment: I am scheduling the exe in Windows Task Scheduler and this causing the task to remain in the "running" state

Comment: How exactly are you starting your app? From Visual Studio with F5 or CTRL+F5?

Comment: Who is printing the "Press any key to continue" then? Because your app doesn't.

Comment: It's probably unrelated but try making your main method `async` and properly `await` the call to `Test()`.